# How To extract data to plot it from a log file

Tags: list-manipulation

i want to extract out the data (number) from 'geometry step' and 'total energy' in form of list to `PlotList[]` it. this is the Log file [data log](http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/dftb.log)

Abstract the Total Energy for every Geometry step in the form of a list, list={{1,TE1},{2,TE2},...,{n,TEn}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Import[
"http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/dftb.\
log", "Table"];
list = Last /@ # & /@ 
Partition[
Cases[data, {"**", "Geometry", "step:", _?NumericQ} | {"Total", 
  "Energy:", _?NumericQ}], 2]
```

Comment: Beat me to it!  You could remove the `Last /@ # & /@ ` if you replace the pattern with `{"**", "Geometry", "step:", a_?NumericQ} | {"Total", "Energy:", 
    a_?NumericQ} :> a]`

Comment: @JasonB great point!